# Python Tkinter: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.4, need 8.5

Tags: python, tcl, version

Using python2.7 Tkinter for executing Tcl.

The Tcl code has `package require Tcl 8.5`, while the tclsh loads Tcl 8.4 by default.

Causes: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.4, need 8.5

I have `libtcl8.5.so` installed at a custom location.
Tried adding it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, TCL_LIBRARY, TCLLIBPATH. Nothing worked. It's like the tclsh completely ignores the envs.

Answer (score 0):

What worked eventually:

    `tcl = Tkinter.tcl()
    tcl.eval('package forget Tcl')
    tcl.eval('package provide Tcl 8.5')
    tcl.eval('package require Tcl')
    8.5`

Success!

Comment: The code probably says `package require Tcl 8.5` because it depends on features added to Tcl in 8.5, such as dictionaries or expansion syntax. What you've done is just putting a timebomb in your code…

Comment: Do you mean that this sequence of command is not clean and may cause problems in tcl execution? I can't upgrade the libtcl in my system. Hence the hack